# Send property value to child component on click

Tags: angular

I have some difficulties understanding the input/output, how to pass data from a component to another component when clicking a button.

Right now I have the `AppComponent` (parent) and the `BasketComponent` (child).

**Code from appComponent.html**

```
<div class="column small-2 navigation-menu-right">
    <span class="basket"><li><a (click)="isClassVisible = !isClassVisible;" href="#"><img src="/assets/img/basket24.png" title=""/></a></li></span>
</div>

<basket-component [isClassVisible]="isClassVisible"></basket-component>
```

**Code from appComponent.ts**

```
export class App {
    name = 'WebShop Angular2 App';
    url = '';
    isClassVisible: boolean = false;

    constructor(public appState: AppState) {

    }
}
```

As  you see, I'm trying to pass in the `isClassVisible` property to the basket component. When you click on the basket button in the `appComponent`, it should send this value to the child `basketComponent`.

**Code from basketComponent.html**

```
<aside class="aside" [ngClass]="{'aside-active': isClassVisible}">
```

I'm using the `ngClass`, so if `isClassVisible` is true, it should add the `aside-active` class.

**Code from basketComponent.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class BasketComponent {

@Input() isClassVisible: boolean; 

    constructor() {

    }

}
```

Have tested my code in one component, and here it works, but want to split it up, so I have a `basketComponent`.

Hope someone can tell me how to use input properly.

**Update:**

```
<aside class="aside" [ngClass]="{'aside-active': isClassVisible }">
<div class="products_in_basket">
    <div class="product_header">
        product header
    </div>
    <div class="product_content">
        <span class="product_quantity">4 stk</span>
        <span class="product_price">1999</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="products_in_basket">

</div>
<div class="price_in_basket">
    <ul>
        <li>price here</li>
        <li>total number</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="">
    <ul>
        <button>Button</button>
    </ul>
</div>
</aside>
```

For some reason, it does not work when the `ngClass` is used on the top tag, like the aside I have made.

I if do something like this:

```
<aside class="aside">
    <div class="products_in_basket" [ngClass]="{'aside-active': isClassVisible }">
```

It works, but I still need to show/hide the whole `aside`. Have also tried with `div` instead of `aside`, that gives the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/wvEMRl5jP1zeyi6TDJFr?p=preview

```
//@Injectable()   //<------This is not required

export class BasketComponent {

@Input() isClassVisible: boolean; 

    constructor() {

    }

}
```

---

```
export class App {
    name = 'WebShop Angular2 App';
    url = '';
    isClassVisible: boolean = false;

    constructor(public appState: AppState) {

    }
}
```

Comment: check my the link which is provided in answer.

Comment: Oh great to hear that. Enjoy !